# Creating objects in Lua from C code

Tags: lua

I want to create a Agent class with defined functions in lua. So, If I have a lua file `soldier.lua` like:

```
function Agent:init()
   io.write("Agent init\n")
   if self then
      self.x = 4
      self:test()
   end
end

function Agent:test()
   io.write("Agent test\n")
end
```

From C code, I can load it, creating the Agent table like:

```
// create Agent class on Lua
lua_newtable( L );
lua_setfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent");
// execute class file
auto ret = luaL_dofile( L, filename.c_str() );
```

Now I want to create a fake object `self` from C to call `Agent:init` and a) the self.x line call a C function to register the data. And the line self.test() call correctly the lua funcion Agent:test. But I can't get it working.

E.g:

```
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
lua_getfield( L, -1, "init");
lua_newtable( L );
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
lua_getmetatable( L, -1 );
lua_pushcfunction( L, testnewindex );
lua_setfield( L, -2, "__newindex" );
ret = lua_pcall( L, 1, 0, 0 );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "But I can get it working" So what's the problem? :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Silly me, fixed :). The question and the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

- Setting metatable on `Agent` after lua file execution
- Using `Agent` as its own fake object when I call file functions:

After the call of `lua_dofile(...)` I put:

```
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
luaL_newmetatable( L, "Agent" );
lua_pushstring(L, "__newindex");
lua_pushcfunction( L, agent_newindex );
lua_settable( L, -3 );
lua_pushstring(L, "__index");
lua_pushcfunction( L, agent_index );
lua_settable( L, -3 );
lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );
```

Then, the call to a the function `Agent:init` is done with:

```
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
lua_getfield( L, -1, "init");
lua_getfield( L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "Agent" );
ret = lua_pcall( L, 1, 0, 0 );
```